# Java is not synthesizing italic font faces

Tags: java, fonts, awt

**Main question:**

Is there a setting in OpenJDK that will synthesize italic font faces like the Oracle JDK does?

**Background:**

Using OpenJDK, when drawing text on a Graphics2D object, text will not appear with an oblique style unless there is an italic font face registered with the desired font family.  Oracle's JDK does synthesize italic font faces.  Swing components also are synthesized.

**Notes:**

- Bold is synthesized, bold italic synthesizes just the bold weight.
- I am aware that for best results, italic font faces should be registered.  This is perhaps not a perfect solution for applications that are already taking advantage of synthesized font faces.
- There is a lot out there about JavaFX and fonts, this is not JavaFX, just AWT.

Here is a simple class that illustrates the issue.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SimpleFontTest {
    private static Font FONT = new Font("Impact", Font.ITALIC, 18);
    private static String TEXT = "The Quick Brown Fox";
    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {     
        if (args.length > 0 && args[0] != null) {
            String fontName = args[0];
            FONT = new Font(fontName, Font.ITALIC, 18);
        }

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Simple Font Test: " + System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("JLabel: " + TEXT);
        label.setFont(FONT);

        GraphicsConfiguration gc = f.getGraphicsConfiguration();
        BufferedImage image = gc.createCompatibleImage(400, 50);
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        g.setFont(FONT);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        g.drawString("BufferedImage: " + TEXT, 10, 15);
        g.dispose();
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    
        f.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        f.add(picLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setSize(400, 200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The output will depend on the JDK used to build and run the class.  Here is a comparison image:

[image]

Comment: I can confirm your problem. But your code shows the same behaviour with Oracle JDK 11.0.1 Win64. Looks like a bug to me. There already some similar bugs in the OpenJDK bug database.

Comment: Thank you for that.  The similar bugs in the OpenJDK bugbase all are related to JavaFX (at least the ones I've seen) - I'll continue looking.  The Oracle JDK 11.0.1 reproduction is interesting.  OpenJDK uses FreeType as the FontScaler.  I wonder if Oracle JDK 11.0.1 also uses FreeType instead of the T2K FontScaler that was previously used.

Comment: Your are right. According to the JDK 11 Release Notes (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html) they are using FreeType.

Comment: I saw that too.  Oh well.  Maybe a bug report is in order.  Thanks again.

Comment: FYI: Bug report has been sent to Oracle.

Comment: @TCCV Do you happen to have the JDK bug number?  I'm running into the same problem with a derived italic font used on a `BufferedImage`.

Comment: Actually, answering my own comment (can't edit it now):  it's probably [JDK-8217712](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8217712), which refers to [JDK-8214002](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8214002), which is **fixed in Java 12** as noted below.

Comment: @Ti Strga That is indeed the bug.  Sorry for not seeing this sooner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because I don't like seeing questions without answers: it looks like this is just a result of the change from T2K font renderer to FreeType.

Some workarounds:

- Make an italic font face (if you are legally allowed to by license)
- Apply an AffineTransform to the Font object (skew of -20 works well).

Comment: For what it's worth, this is fixed in Java 12 (links to bugs above), which I've confirmed after encountering the same bug myself.  However, as Java 11 is the current-as-I-write-this LTS release, this kind of workaround may be needed for a couple years yet as large organizations are likely to only upgrade to the next LTS release.