# Can Java Indicate If a Font Is Italic

Tags: java, fonts, awt

This is related to [Java is not Synthesizing Italic Font Faces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54314653/245108), which I asked previously.

Is there a way to determine if a Font object is *really* italic (not that an italic font face was requested)?

In my testing Font.isItalic(), Font.getStyle(), Font.getAttributes() all indicate that a Font object is italic if it was created with the Font.ITALIC style.  This does not take into account whether a proper italic font face was found.  The result is that a Font object that, for all intents and purposes, is italic but actually renders plain and you can't programmatically check for this condition.

This affects Oracle JDK 11 and OpenJDK.

Example Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class SimpleFontTest {
    private static Font FONT = new Font("Impact", Font.ITALIC, 18);
    private static String TEXT = "The Quick Brown Fox";

    public static void main(String args[]){     
        if (args.length > 0 && args[0] != null) {
            String fontName = args[0];
            FONT = new Font(fontName, Font.ITALIC, 18);
        }

        // All the different ways that this proves the font is italic
        System.out.println("isItalic? " + FONT.isItalic());
        System.out.println("style is Font.ITALIC? " + ((FONT.getStyle() & 0b10) == Font.ITALIC));
        System.out.println("attributes include POSTURE_OBLIQUE? " + FONT.getAttributes().get(TextAttribute.POSTURE).equals(TextAttribute.POSTURE_OBLIQUE));

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Simple Font Test: " + System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("JLabel: " + TEXT);
        label.setFont(FONT);

        GraphicsConfiguration gc = f.getGraphicsConfiguration();
        BufferedImage image = gc.createCompatibleImage(400, 50);
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        g.setFont(FONT);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        g.drawString("BufferedImage: " + TEXT, 10, 15);
        g.dispose();
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));

        f.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        f.add(picLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setSize(400, 200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

SYSOUT:

```
isItalic? true 
style is Font.ITALIC? true 
attributes include POSTURE_OBLIQUE? true
```

Graphical Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround (so far).  java.awt.Font will not properly indicate the style.  You can use Font2D, though.  Here's a sample of what I needed.

```
String fontname = "someArbitraryString";
FontManager fm = FontManagerFactory.getInstance();
Font2D f2d = fm.findFont2D(fontName, Font.ITALIC, FontManager.LOGICAL_FALLBACK);
boolean isItalic = (f2d.getStyle() & 0b10) == Font.ITALIC);
```

Comment: Font2D?? are you referring to some out of space libraries??? what on earth are you talking about??

Comment: it's in the JDK, sun.font.Font2D.  https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/font/Font2D.java

Comment: Font2D source link in OpenJDK project: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/client/file/9fb26c4d8eaa/src/java.desktop/share/classes/sun/font/Font2D.java

Comment: The java compiler warns you against using sun.* classes.  As of Java 9, you cannot use them at all.